# How do you access controls when using <TabItem.Header>, in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabitem

Going off this sample from the MSDN under TabControl:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="DarkGray"/>
        <TextBlock>Tab 1</TextBlock>
      </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock>Enter some text</TextBlock>
      <TextBox Name="textBox1" Width="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
    <!--Bind TextBlock.Text to the TextBox on the first
    TabItem.-->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=Text}"/>
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

How do you access the stackpanel (and it's children) that is inside the `<TabItem.Header>` tag from C# code behind? When I try to use `.Header` intellisense treats it as if the header was defined the way the 2nd tab above is.

Comment: What do you want that for? whatever you're trying to do here, you should be using databinding, instead of trying to manipulate the UI elements in procedural code.

Comment: In order to access the controls from code-behind, they must have a name.  `<TabItem Name="TabItem1"> .... </TabItem>` and then in the code-behind, you can access it by: `TabItem1.Header` or whatever property you are trying to access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with HighCore.  You should be using databinding instead of trying to manipulate the UI elements directly.  In the off chance that you want to stick with your current plan, here's how:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
      <StackPanel Name="tab1StackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
        ...
      </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>        
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
    ...
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Now, from code behind you can reference `tab1StackPanel` directly, as defining a `Name` exposes it to codebehind WPF (as long as it's not inside a template).

You could also use the VisualTreeHelper to find visual children of the first tab...

***BUT***... once again, you should probably be using databinding, so I'd make sure you're following a good pattern before going too much further.

Comment: This was a bit of self learning figure-it-out, and after some more research I came up with a much better way using binding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works but you can give it a try:

```
(tabItem.Header as ContentControl).FindName("NAME_OF_TEXTBLOCK");
```